# datagridviewcombobox columns Dependent on another column

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridviewcombobox

> How To Do This Work on gridviewcomboboxcolumns any idea plx
>
> //Form Load Event

```
string query="select article_name from article";
SqlCommmand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
SqlDataAdapter da= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
combobox1.items.clear();
for(int i=0;i<dt.rows.count;i++)
{
 combobox1.items.add(dt.rows[i].cells[0].toString());
}
```

> \ComboBox1 Selected IndexChange Event

```
string query1="select description from article where article_name='"+combobox1.selectedItem.ToString()+"'";
SqlCommmand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1,con);
SqlDataAdapter da1= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt1=new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);
combobox2.items.clear();
for(int i=0;i<dt1.rows.count;i++)
{
 combobox2.items.add(dt1.rows[i].cells[0].toString());
}
```

> \Now Assume these 2 combox is gridviewCombobox Columns so how to make
>   this work on gridviewcombobox columns

```
Project in Windows Form in C#
```

Comment: same problem bro and i also need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I m posting this `answer` after a few months because its helps for
>   thoose whoose facing problem on `DataGridviewComboboxcell`
>   I did my own skill First Fill my first/Main Column

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct article_name from Setup_article_custominvoice", con);
                    SqlDataAdapter objDA = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
                    objDA.SelectCommand.CommandText = objCmd.CommandText.ToString();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    objDA.Fill(dt);
                    article.DataSource = dt;
                    //this column1 will display as text
                    article.DisplayMember = "article_name";
```

> After that i was going on  `Cell End Edit`

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["article_name"])
                {
                    string CategoryValue = "";
                    //string CategoryValue1 = "";

                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
                    {
                        CategoryValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                        //CategoryValue1 = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    //SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=dbTest3;Integrated Security=True");
                    string query = "select article_name,composition from Setup_article_custominvoice where article_name='" + CategoryValue + "'";
                    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                    SqlDataAdapter objDA = new SqlDataAdapter(objCmd);

                    objDA.SelectCommand.CommandText = objCmd.CommandText.ToString();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    objDA.Fill(dt);

                    DataGridViewComboBoxCell t = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                    t.DataSource = dt;
                    t.DisplayMember = "composition";

                }
```